# How to improve broadcast Join speed with between condition in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes A and B. A is large (100 G) and B is relatively small (100 M). Partition number of A is 8 and Partition number of B is 1.

```scala
A.join(broadcast(B), $"cur" >= $"low" &&  $"cur" <= $"high", "left_outer")
```

The speed is pretty slow (> 10 hours).

But if I change the join condition to:

```scala
A.join(broadcast(B), $"cur" === $"low" , "left_outer")
```

It becomes extremely fast (< 30 minutes). But the condition cannot be changed.

So are there any ways to further improve the join speed on my original join condition?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The trick is to rewrite `join` condition so it contains `=` component which can be used to optimize the query and narrow down possible matches. For numeric values you bucketize your data and use buckets for join condition.

Let's say your data looks like this:

```scala
val a = spark.range(100000)
  .withColumn("cur", (rand(1) * 1000).cast("bigint"))

val b = spark.range(100)
  .withColumn("low", (rand(42) * 1000).cast("bigint"))
  .withColumn("high", ($"low" + rand(-42) * 10).cast("bigint"))
```

First choose a bucket size appropriate for your data. In this case we can use 50:

```scala
val bucketSize = 50L
```

Assign bucket for each row from `a`:

```scala
val aBucketed = a.withColumn(
  "bucket", ($"cur" / bucketSize).cast("bigint") * bucketSize
)
```

Create UDF which will emit buckets for a range:

```scala
def get_buckets(bucketSize: Long) = 
  udf((low: Long, high: Long) => {
    val min = (low / bucketSize) * bucketSize
    val max = (high / bucketSize) * bucketSize
    (min to max by bucketSize).toSeq
  })
```

and bucket `b`:

```scala
val bBucketed = b.withColumn(
  "bucket", explode(get_buckets(bucketSize)($"low",  $"high"))
)
```

use bucket in `join` condition:

```scala
aBucketed.join(
  broadcast(bBucketed), 
  aBucketed("bucket") === bBucketed("bucket") && 
    $"cur" >= $"low" &&  
    $"cur" <= $"high",
  "leftouter"
)
```

This way Spark will use `BroadcastHashJoin`:

```
*BroadcastHashJoin [bucket#184L], [bucket#178L], LeftOuter, BuildRight, ((cur#98L >= low#105L) && (cur#98L <= high#109L))
:- *Project [id#95L, cur#98L, (cast((cast(cur#98L as double) / 50.0) as bigint) * 50) AS bucket#184L]
:  +- *Project [id#95L, cast((rand(1) * 1000.0) as bigint) AS cur#98L]
:     +- *Range (0, 100000, step=1, splits=Some(8))
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[3, bigint, false]))
   +- Generate explode(if ((isnull(low#105L) || isnull(high#109L))) null else UDF(low#105L, high#109L)), true, false, [bucket#178L]
      +- *Project [id#102L, low#105L, cast((cast(low#105L as double) + (rand(-42) * 10.0)) as bigint) AS high#109L]
         +- *Project [id#102L, cast((rand(42) * 1000.0) as bigint) AS low#105L]
            +- *Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=Some(8))
```

instead of `BroadcastNestedLoopJoin`:

```
== Physical Plan ==
BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, LeftOuter, ((cur#98L >= low#105L) && (cur#98L <= high#109L))
:- *Project [id#95L, cast((rand(1) * 1000.0) as bigint) AS cur#98L]
:  +- *Range (0, 100000, step=1, splits=Some(8))
+- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode
   +- *Project [id#102L, low#105L, cast((cast(low#105L as double) + (rand(-42) * 10.0)) as bigint) AS high#109L]
      +- *Project [id#102L, cast((rand(42) * 1000.0) as bigint) AS low#105L]
         +- *Range (0, 100, step=1, splits=Some(8))
```

You can tune bucket size to balance between precision and data size.

If you don't mind a lower level solution then `broadcast` a sorted sequence with constant item access (like `Array` or `Vector`) and use `udf` with binary search for joining.

You should also take a look at the number of partitions. 8 partitions for 100GB seems pretty low.

**See also**:

- [SPARK-8682](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8682) - *Range Join for Spark SQL*
- [SPARK-22947](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22947) - *SPIP: as-of join in Spark SQL*
- [Spark SQL performance - JOIN on value BETWEEN min and max](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37953830)

Answer (score 4):

You can do a ranged join using Apache DataFu - it should look something like this:

`A.joinWithRange(B, "cur", "low", "high", 50)`

This function is using bucketing like suggested by zero323 in his answer, with `50` being the number of buckets, or the decrease factor.

Here is a link to the blog post about DataFu-Spark, which talks about this kind of join: [https://medium.com/paypal-tech/introducing-datafu-spark-ba67faf1933a](https://medium.com/paypal-tech/introducing-datafu-spark-ba67faf1933a#:%7E:text=Joining%20a%20table%20with%20a%20numeric%20column%20with%20a%20table%20with%20a%20range%20%E2%80%94%20the%20joinWithRange%20method)