# How to join datasets with values between other values?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a use case where I need to join 2 data-frames.

ID view

```
ID  BookTime
1   2
1   5
2   8
2   3
3   4
```

FareRule view

```
Start End Fare
1   3   10
3   6   20
6   10  25
```

Output is a result of join by checking the `BookTime` from the `ID` table. The `Fare` is computed based on the window that is between `Start` and `End` from `FareRule`.

```
ID  FareDue
1   10
1   20
2   25
2   20
3   20
```

I am creating a view out of these data-frames and using CROSS JOIN to join them. But as we know, CROSS join is expensive so is there a better way to join them?

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    Fare AS FareDue 
FROM 
    ID 
CROSS JOIN 
    FareRule 
WHERE 
   BookTime >=Start 
   AND 
   BookTime< End
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to improve broadcast Join speed in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483576/how-to-improve-broadcast-join-speed-in-spark)

Comment: Why are you using _cross_ join? From the looks of it you sgould be getting the same result with a regular join.

Comment: Like other SQL query engines Spark has a query optimizer & there is no difference between CROSS JOIN (or comma) with WHERE vs INNER JOIN ON. Read about the general idea of relational query optimization/implementation anywhere. (Including dozens of published academic textbooks free online in pdf.) Read about the optimizer Catalyst & writing optimal Spark SQL queries anywhere. (Many implementers who authored the ACM paper "Spark SQL: Relational Data Processing in Spark" work at Databricks.) PS What did you learn from googling re spark sql query optimization before you considered asking?

Answer (score -1):

Given the following datasets:

```
val id = Seq((1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 8), (2, 3), (3, 4)).toDF("ID", "BookTime")
scala> id.show
+---+--------+
| ID|BookTime|
+---+--------+
|  1|       2|
|  1|       5|
|  2|       8|
|  2|       3|
|  3|       4|
+---+--------+

val fareRule = Seq((1,3,10), (3,6,20), (6,10,25)).toDF("start", "end", "fare")
scala> fareRule.show
+-----+---+----+
|start|end|fare|
+-----+---+----+
|    1|  3|  10|
|    3|  6|  20|
|    6| 10|  25|
+-----+---+----+
```

You simply `join` them together using `between` expression.

```
val q = id.join(fareRule).where('BookTime between('start, 'end)).select('id, 'fare)
scala> q.show
+---+----+
| id|fare|
+---+----+
|  1|  10|
|  1|  20|
|  2|  25|
|  2|  10|
|  2|  20|
|  3|  20|
+---+----+
```

You may want to adjust `between` so the boundaries are exclusive on one side. `between` by default uses the lower bound and upper bound, inclusive.