# Why is join on dates + filter on timestamps faster than joining on time-range in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, timestamp, time-series

I have a dataframe `X` containing some events (points in time, with timestamps) and another dataframe `Y` containing time-ranges (also specified by timestamps.)

Through experimentation and [some reading](https://rahulpedduri.github.io/2017/10/23/time-range-join.html) I found that the basic approach of join on timestamps directly:

```
return X.join(Y, (X.ts >= Y.start_ts) & (X.ts < Y.end_ts), "inner")
```

Turns up to be much slower than first join on dates and then filter on specific timestamps:

```
X = X.withColumn("event_date", ts.cast('date'))
Y = Y.withColumn("date", explode(array([start_ts.cast('date')), end_ts.cast('date'))])))
return X \
    .join(Y, (X.event_date == Y.date), "inner") \
    .filter((X.ts >= Y.start_ts) & (X.ts < Y.end_ts))
```

To my understanding, the basic approach to execute the join in the first example would be:

1. Order X by `ts` and Y by `start_ts` and then `end_ts` (Possible in nlogn in Spark?)
2. The join can then be executed linearly, with at most 2 `long` comparisons per candidate

In the second example:

1. Linearly run a cast to date, doubling the datasize with explosion
2. Order both dataframes by dates (nlogn, smaller constant at most 2x)
3. Execute the join linearly, at most 1 `long` comparison per candidate
4. Linearly filter the result with at most 2 `long` comparisons per row

Is the smaller constant from point 2 in second example enough to speed it up so much? Or is there some Spark optimization involved that makes the perf behave this way?

Answer (score 0):

For starters these two methods are in general not logically equivalent, so comparing their execution time makes little sense in practice. Just imagine the case where `Y.start_ts` is always the smallest representable value, and `Y.end_ts` is the largest representable value. It is clear from the context that you don't allow such case, but that's a domain specific knowledge, not something that can be easily inferred by the planner.

As of the actual execution the difference is simple but fundamental:

- The first case simply performs a Cartesian Product and then filters the data, making always N * M comparisons.
- The second case shuffles the data and compares average-number-of-records-per-day-in-the-first-set * average-number-of-records-per-day-in-the-second-set comparisons.

See [How to improve broadcast Join speed with between condition in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43483576) for details.