# Pyspark rdd : 'RDD' object has no attribute 'flatmap'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am new to Pyspark and I am actually trying to build a flatmap out of a Pyspark RDD object. However, even if this function clearly exists for pyspark RDD class, according to the documentation, I can't manage to use it and get the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'flatmap'
```

I am calling the latter function in the following line :

```
my_rdd = my_rdd.flatmap(lambda r: (r[5].split('|')))
```

The imports are the followings :

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext as sc
from pyspark import SparkFiles
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

Additionaly, some other functions, as my_rdd.count are working, which let me think that the SparkContext is correctly implemented.

Do you have any ideas about the reason why it could fail ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
my_rdd = my_rdd.flatMap(lambda r: (r[5].split('|')))
```

uppercase !!!

Comment: These things happen, the forest for the trees

Comment: I'm still experiencing `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'flatMap'`

Comment: Not how it works. @jeremy

Comment: This post, call this function on DataFrame: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37955947/3710514

Comment: This question was about rdd's not dataframes. Pls post a new question.